# Another database design question

Tags: database-design

I'm desing a database and I have following structure:

Is a game database, and I will have users, games and groups.

```
A game will have 1 owner (an user). In other words a game will be created by an user.
A game will have 1..n groups.

A group will have 1 owner (an user). In other words a group will be created by an user.
A group will have 1..n users.

A user will belong to a group. The user can't belong to more that ONE group.
A user will belong to a game. The user can't belong to more than ONE game.
```

I don't know how to know which user has created a game. I thought in two possibilities:

- add a foreign key from game table to
  user table.
- add a column in user table, called
  gameOwner, and set it to true if user
  has created a game.

Here are my tables:

```
User
--------------------------------------
Id                  | PK
Name                | User name (not null)
GroupOwner          | Bool type. True if user has created a group.
GroupId             | FK to group table. Can be null: user is not playing any game now.


Group
--------------------------------------
Id                  | PK
Name                | Group name (not null)
GameId              | FK to game table. Group belongs to this game.


Game
--------------------------------------
Id                  | PK
Name                | Game name (not null).
```

How can I represent that a user has created a game?

**UPDATE**
A game always needs an owner.
Game's owner will be always the same.
When a game is finished can be deleted.

Comment: Q1: Will a game's owner always be the same? e.g. what happens over time?
Q2: Does a Game need an owner to exist ie a game ALWAYS has to have an owner?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details (and your answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common and natural way to represent the ownership relation you've described is to have foreign keys in the Group and Game Tables to the User table.

If you do this you shouldn't need flag fields in the User table signifying whether the user is an owner.  This can be determined by a query.

I'd go with

```
User
--------------------------------------
Id                  | PK
Name                | User name (not null)
GroupId             | FK to group table. Can be null: user is not playing any game now.


Group
--------------------------------------
Id                  | PK
Name                | Group name (not null)
GameId              | FK to game table. Group belongs to this game.
OwnerId             | FK to User table. Group belongs to this user.


Game
--------------------------------------
Id                  | PK
Name                | Game name (not null).
OwnerId             | FK to User table. Game belongs to this user.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use this, I will have a reference from User to Group, and a reference from Group to User. Is this a problem? I had chosen to add a GroupOwner column in User table to avoid this.

Comment: You should be able to have both references, one representing membership and the other referencing ownership.  If a user is always a member of the owned group, using the flag instead of the foreign key could indeed work to identify the owner, but this is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Ill say add a userID field to the group and game table which refers to the user that is the owner of the group or game.